# Turn a Ruby Array built from a mongoid query into an actual mongoid object, or re write method to return a mongoid object?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a mongoid model called `Department` and a separate model called `User`, and there is no native relationship between the two models. Because of how the relationships in my application work, I manually store document ID's on the User model.

I am using the `Grape` framework for Ruby, and it has a filter system that sits on top of Mongoid objects called `Entities`, and it rejects anything that isnt a mongoid query response object, because this method returns a ruby Array instead of a Mongoid object, my framework gives me errors.

Is there any way to re write my function to return a Mongoid object? or is there any way I can convert an array of Mongoid Objects into one Mongoid object?

```
## inside Department Model
def self.user_can_access(user = nil)
  if user != nil
    departments = []
    ## department_access_keys are embedded documents belonging to a user
    user.department_access_keys.each do |key|
      departments << BACKBONE::Department.find(key.key)
    end
    departments ## => returns an array of Department Documents that a user has been granted access to
  else
    raise 'user was not defined'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use `find` like this?

```
departments = BACKBONE::Department.find(*user.department_access_keys.map(&:key))
```

I am not very familiar with `mongoid` but the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-queries/#additional-query-methods) seems to suggest that this is exactly how to achieve what you want.

> Criteria#find
>   Find a document or multiple documents by their ids. Will raise an error by default if any of the ids do not match.

**Examples:**

```
Band.find("4baa56f1230048567300485c")
Band.find(
  "4baa56f1230048567300485c",
  "4baa56f1230048567300485d"
)
Band.where(name: "Photek").find(
  "4baa56f1230048567300485c"
)
```

Comment: thank you! I have no idea why Grape Entities don't accept arrays, but this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I believe, “Mongoid Object” should be just a hash, so this should work (also note `Enumerable.map` instead of phpish `each { << }`):

```
## inside Department Model
def self.user_can_access(user = nil)
  raise 'user was not defined' if user.nil?

  {
    departments: # return hash here
      user.department_access_keys.map do |key|
        BACKBONE::Department.find(key.key)
      end
  }
end
```